# UICollectionView, button not appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, ios-simulator

I am still fairly new to programming and I do not quite understand UICollectionViews.  Can a programmer add buttons in the cells of an UICollectionView? Or only UIImages? I added a button into one of the cells and when I ran the iOS simulator nothing appeared.  I also just dragged in an UICollectionView and I am not using an UICollectionView view controller.  I dragged the UICollectionView into code as an outlet too and constrained the view, cell and button.  Attached is a screenshot of my view controller and iOS simulator.  Thanks!!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was recently new to collection views, and they can be confusing. I found a video tutorial that explains it all really well, but it was not updated for Swift 3 so I wrote made [this GitHub project](https://github.com/DuffyScottC/CollectionViewTutorial) to help explain it to new users.

You can certainly add buttons to to the cells of a UICollectionView. Each cell is like a little UIView in and of itself. However, I believe you need to create a new class for the cell and create an IBOutlet for the button. You also need to create a couple of functions inside your main ViewController.swift file to actually view the UICollectionView. It can be complicated at first, but stick it out! In a little while, you'll be able to do them with ease. Follow the tutorial in a new project to practice, then you might figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that that last one was unhelpful, I'm new to this. Thanks for the tip, manetsus!

I created a new project and tried to add a button to the UICollectionViewCell. Here's what I did:

I added a button to the cell, then created an IBAction by control+dragging from the button to ViewController.swift. I ran it, and it worked. Each button within the UICollectionView cells performs the IBAction in ViewController.swift.

If you want cell-specific actions, consider using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    //Do something with the cell...

}
```